# Grails, MySQL and extended classes

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, abstract, extends

Here is my abstract class :

```
package mypackage.commons

abstract class Content {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, size: 1..50
    }
}
```

Here is my class which is extended :

```
package mypackage.project

import mypackage.commons.Content

class Plane extends Content {
    String something;
}
```

Here is my Bootstrap.groovy file :

```
package mypackage

import mypackage.commons.Content
import mypackage.project.Plane

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        Plane boing1 = new Plane (name: 'Boing', something: 'Hello').save()
        Plane boing2 = new Plane (name: 'Boing', something: 'Goodbye').save()
        
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

The problem is when I go on MySQL, when I use **SHOW TABLES**, I only can see **content** **plane**.

Here is the content of **SELECT * FROM content;**

```
+----+---------+-------+-------------------------+-----------+
| id | version | name  | class                   | something |
+----+---------+-------+-------------------------+-----------+
|  1 |       0 | Boing | mypackage.project.Plane | Hello     |
|  2 |       0 | Boing | mypackage.project.Plane | Goodbye   |
+----+---------+-------+-------------------------+-----------+
```

**EDIT**

After testing Mike's answer :

```
package mypackage.commons

abstract class Content {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, size: 1..50
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}
```

here is the result of **SHOW TABLES**

```
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_my_database |
+-----------------------+
|  content              |
|  plane                |
+-----------------------+
```

Here is the result of **SELECT * FROM content** :

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | version | name  |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |       0 | Boing |
|  2 |       0 | Boing |
+----+---------+-------+
```

Here is the result of **SELECT * FROM plane** :

```
+----+------------+
| id |  something |
+----+------------+
|  1 |  Hello     |
|  2 |  Goodbye   |
+----+------------+
```

**END OF EDIT**

Expected behaviour :

**SHOW TABLES;** should show me only the table **plane**

**SELECT * FROM plane** should show me this :

```
+----+---------+-------+------------+
| id | version | name  |  something |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
|  1 |       0 | Boing |  Hello     |
|  2 |       0 | Boing |  Goodbye   |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
```

How can I obtain the expected result ?

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, I wonder if it's the best way, but it works.

This topic helps me : https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/1254

Firstly, I understand that if I don't want a class to be mapped by Grails, I have to put this class outside of "Domain" package.

So I moove my Content class into src -> main -> groovy -> common (I created this folder) -> Content.groovy

Here is my Content class :

```
package common

abstract class Content {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, size: 1..50
    }
}
```

Here is my Plane class :

```
package mypackage.project

import common.Content

class Plane extends Content {
    String something;
}
```

And here is my Bootstrap.groovy :

```
package mypackage

import mypackage.project.Plane

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        Plane boing1 = new Plane (name: 'Boing', something: 'Hello').save()
        Plane boing2 = new Plane (name: 'Boing', something: 'Goodbye').save()
        
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

So I avoid tablePerHierarchy use.

In the topic, thay talked about @MappedSupperclass, I don't know what it refers to. I did not use it.

Expected behaviour is reach.

Is it the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Grails to use table-per-subclass strategy by telling it not to use table-per-hierarchy like:

```
package mypackage.commons

abstract class Content {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, size: 1..50
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer, but this does not work as expected. I now have the table "Content" with "Boing" and "Boing"in column "name" and the table "plane" with "Hello" and "GoodBye" in column "something". I wonder how Grails can map tables in that configuration, and the expected behaviour is not reach.

Comment: I edited my original post with the result of your answer.